# Chrome Console - click function : error (Clicking a link multiple times)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

**Body Content:**

`<a href"http://example.com/open.php" id="open" target="_blank">`

**Console Syntax:**

`for (var c = 0; c < 200; c++)
{ document.getElementById("open").click(); }`

***Error:*** `undefined`

Further, 
`document.getElementById("open").click();` gives the same error.

Please explain why I'm experiencing this error.

I need to click a link with id `open` multiple times.

This is for a project I need to test. Thanks for your help.

Comment: .click() is a jQuery function.

Comment: @howderek That's why _they_ said, learn javascript first!

Comment: If you want to use .click() you have to use JQuery though: `$("#open").click()`, and to use JQuery you have to include it first. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Also, you won't be able to click the link multiple times from the same script because when you click the link you will be redirected.

Comment: @howderek I'm not sure how to load jquery in console. Currently the page doesn't have jquery file, if I give ref to jquery file then it will work?

Comment: You will have to include it `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @howderek Thanks :) and I have a fix for that, `target="_blank"`

Comment: Did you close your `<a>` tag with `</a>`? I would learn the concepts of JS before working with jQuery

Comment: Yes, I did close `<a>` with `</a>`. It is the second mistake of my life - jQuery before JS :)

Comment: @howderek For some odd reason - I still get the same error. _`undefined`_

Comment: What was the first mistake? :D

Comment: Did you use `$("#open").click()`?

Comment: Perhaps working on dumb (hey I don't call them dumb) projects when I have exam tomorrow.

Comment: Ahh I see. Wow, so your life was mistake free before that, thats pretty good.

Comment: Yes. I corrected that, it doesn't seem to open the link and it shows `[]`

Comment: It won't open the link. jQuery .click() works by calling the event handler associated with the object. It cannot call native behaviors.

Comment: Is there any way to open the link via console or I should stop trying?

Comment: If you want to redirect use `document.location = "http://example.com";`